# jquery to total dropdown values returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add the values of several dropdowns  using jquesry as folows:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var val1 = $("#Qty_0").val();
  var val2 = $("#Qty_1").val();
  var sum = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2);
  $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="now" for="Qty_0">Quantity 1</label>
<select name="Qty[]" id="Qty_0"><option value="">Please select ...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<label class="now" for="Qty_1">Quantity 1</label>
<select name="Qty[]" id="Qty_1"><option value="">Please select ...</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id=sum></div>
```

This always returns an NaN eror, using the || 0 set these to 0 confirming the NaN error but how do I get this to work? Is there anyway to see teh var values within the developer tools?

Comment: Use `#` with id selector, i.e. `$("#Qty_0")`, I thinks its typo while posting and use `radix` while using `parseInt` i.e. `parseInt(val1, 10)`

Comment: you haven't provided select with id #Qty_2. If it is not by mistake, It can cause the NaN output

Comment: If both of the above were just typo's provide us a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem in full.

Comment: @Satpal Thanks, yes typo, missing #, on the post now corrected. I have added teh radix value but still see the NaN error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of `||` and set value of variable's `val1` and `val2` as `0` when selected value is falsely i.e. `""` .

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var val1 = $("#Qty_0").val() || 0;
  var val2 = $("#Qty_1").val() || 0;
  var sum = parseInt(val1, 10) + parseInt(val2, 10);
  $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="now" for="Qty_0">Quantity 1</label>
<select name="Qty[]" id="Qty_0">
  <option value="">Please select ...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<label class="now" for="Qty_1">Quantity 2</label>
<select name="Qty[]" id="Qty_1">
  <option value="">Please select ...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id=sum></div>
```